# How to make `mapped` a virtual fields in Symfony

Tags: symfony

I have a virtual fields in my Entity, that have no relation to database, but i use it in my form.

I want use it in `preUpdate` event listener to populate a real field, but `preUpdate` rise up only on change a real fields, not virtual.

How to make that `preUpdate` event rise up on virtual fields change?

Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your virtual fields have no mappings in database - Doctrine doesn't even know about them because it takes information about entity from `ClassMetadata`, not from object itself.

You need to handle all required logic for these virtual fields manually. Most likely you need to add listener to [`preFlush`](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/events.html#preflush) event and implement your own events generation mechanism.

Comment: I thought that there is a simple solution. But thank you very much for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can always try changing data using form events. For example calculate data via some helper service add value to your entity mapped field after form is being submitted.